# Facing problem in code injector program . The program is not showing HTML code of a http website

Tags: python, code-injection, scapy, netfilter

I am learning ethical hacking from udemy, and I was making a code_injector program. Here is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy
import re


def set_load(packet , load):
    packet[scapy_packet.Raw].load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet


def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:
        print("[+] Request")
            modified_load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?\\r\\n", "", scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load)
            new_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, modified_load)
            packet.set_payload(str(new_packet))
        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:
            print("[+] Response")
            print(scapy_packet.show())


    packet.accept()

queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

After running this code I got the error

```
Exception NameError: "global name 'scapy_packet' is not defined" in 
'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: _What might be causing this?_ What do/don't you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

`scapy_packet` is undefined in your `set_load` function, which is causing this `'scapy_packet' is not defined` error.

It makes more sense to just set `load` of the packet like below. If the packet has a load, it will be replaced and if it doesn't, it will be set:

```py
def set_load(packet, load):
    packet.load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet
```